# ASP .NET MVC dynamic column name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

the database table has fields like this:

```
fld_column1
fld_column1_item_1
fld_column1_item_2
fld_column1_item_3
fld_column2
fld_column2_item_1
fld_column2_item_2
fld_column2_item_3
fld_column3
fld_column3_item_1
fld_column3_item_2
fld_column3_item_3
```

and i did this in the controller:

```
ViewBag.Columns = from col in _db.tbl_columns
      select col;
      return View();
```

In the view i did this:

```
<% foreach (tbl_columns col in (IEnumerable)ViewBag.Columns)
    { %>

      <%= col.fld_column1_item1 %>
      <%= col.fld_column2_item1 %>
      <%= col.fld_column3_item1 %>

    <% } %>
```

Now my qyestion is very simple: is it possible to add a variable that automates this "column1", "column2" etc? And how could I use it?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what these columns actually hold (e.g., what their names are?) That'd make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: You really should be using a model rather than the viewbag for bringing collections to the view.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker the column names are just like i have posted above, and they hold menu names.
Chris im not very sure if i got you right. Could you please post a very short sample? :)

Comment: You would have a view model, one of the properties would be  Collection. So you would have return View(Model) and in the view you would access it Model.Collection. Then you can spin over it like this: forearch(var item in Model.Collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could change your table schema and this would be very easy to do at that point.

New Table Schema:

```
Id  Column   Item   ParentId
1    1        null   null
2    1        1      1
3    1        2      1
3    1        3      1
4    2        null   null
5    2        1      4
6    2        2      4
6    2        3      4
7    3        null   null
8    3        1      7
9    3        2      7
9    3        3      7
```

Now, you can just iterate through each of them by the following (psuedo-ish code):

```
foreach (var rows in columns)
{
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        <%= row.Item %>
    }
}
```

Comment: the table schema for this project has been made like that and I just have to do the rest of the project :) however I also think it should be different, just like you mentioned and I will have to discuss this and decide. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others, you should be using a view model.  However, with the current table structure, you will still need to iterate through your model and display each property.  If you have the ability to change the db schema I would flatten it out as suggested by George Stocker.